# IntelliJ 12: Cannot find Play 2 install dir

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I have been struggling with importing an existing web app built with Play 2 into IntelliJ all day. Finally, after upgrading from 12.0.3 to 12.1.7, all the syntax errors vanished, and I thought all was good, but one error remained. When setting up a new run configuration for Play 2 and pressing "Play", I get the following error

*Error running Unnamed: Cannot find Play 2 install dir*

This is a bit weird, as the project compiles and I can get it to run just fine from the command line using `play run`. Setting up a new Play 2 project in IntelliJ from scratch using the Wizards, choosing to download a Play installation through IntelliJ works fine, but I seem unable to replicate that when importing an existing application. Also, setting "Use non-default Play 2 install dir" in the Run configuration to point to an installation only gives me errors about libraries in the wrong version, whereas setting the same option to the Play downloaded with Homebrew (2.2.2) does not work at all.

Comment: I also have this issue. did you manage to find a resolution? I have to add that this issue only exists with a play 2.2.1 inherited project

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually set the play dir in my project for it to work by doing the following:
Go to "**Run -> Edit configurations**" , tick the "Use non-default Play 2 install dir" option  and put in the path to your play2 installation directory.